# Should questions about drivers for gaming hardware go to Arqade or Super User?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a Razer gaming keyboard which uses a driver/software package called Razer Synapse. This software is required to change many of the functions of the keyboard, such as lighting, macros, profiles, settings etc.

**I have a question about how to use a specific function in this software.** I know that either [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) would probably be the best sites to ask my question on, but I'm not sure which.

What site should I ask my question on?

Answer (score 1):

**[Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/razer-keyboard)**

The question in it's broad self (help with configuring, setting up and settings) is suited on Super User more than Arqade.

However, if the question asks about a specific setting regarding to a specific game, then it would be more at home in Arqade than SuperUser.